# iPhone Web Development Image Scaling

Tags: iphone, safari, image-scaling

I am developing a simple web page to be viewed after an iphone application completes.  I am finding the safari degrades the image quality of the jpg so its all fuzzy.

The image is background image applied to a div

```
div.foo
{
    background: url(../images/foo.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:320px;
    height:349px;
}
```

The width and height are exactly the same as the jpg image.  Is there a way to make sure the image gets displayed in its full quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  The iphone "optimises" jpg's, compressing them to minimise the file size but destroying the quality of the image.  All the reading I did suggested there was no way to switch this "feature" off.

The solution is simple, switch to pngs.

Comment: Is there a document/article on this that I can read? What's the source of your discovery?

Comment: Sorry, this was so long ago I can't remember.